# Spring Security: make endpoint controller only accessible with Authorization: Bearer token header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to get an endpoint not accessible (`503` error?) without `Authorization: Bearer token` header

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/api/admin/**")
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                exceptionHandling()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class AdminController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String testAdmin()  {
        return "OK; secret test admin";
    }
}
```

however I can access it just fine
What should I change in my configure method?

**EDIT**:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder
                                .getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
           
            UserDetails userDetails = this
                    .userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

          
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

It seems that the `jwtRequestFilter`'s `doFilterInternal` method never runs: I tried setting the breakpoints in the debugger and the execution never stopped there.

**EDIT**: whole `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public SecurityConfig(
            UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService)  {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring();
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }


    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post more info about how you are making this call? also, could you post the code for the `jwtRequestFilter`? running on my local machine, I was able to get the desired `403` without that additional filter step

Comment: @bluesky33 I just send a POST request to `https://localhost:8080/testproject/api/admin/test` endpoint without any headers

Comment: @bluesky33 Added the `JwtRequestFilter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Turns out the problem was in me not having correct configurations, so the `SecurityConfig` never even got applied. I fixed it this way:

**WebConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("testproject")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "testproject",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
 public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
bean.setSuffix(".html");


        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()  {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService =
                new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

**MyAppInitializer.java** (notice the commented out `sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));` line, it **must** be like that, otherwise there are errors - the fix was suggested to me in another SO question):

```
public class MyAppInitializer extends
                AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("onStartup!");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.register(WebConfig.class);
        root.setServletContext(sc);

        root.scan("testproject");
        //sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet =
                sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");
    }

        @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
                    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class, WebConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP response 503 means service unavailable. You should get 401 Unauthorized when token is missing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {    
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
        // dont authenticate this particular request
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()        
        // all other requests need to be authenticated
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()        
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

Using AuthenticationEntryPoint.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
  
  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work - can still get the response from `/api/admin/test`

Comment: You are using 2 styles of injection one by @Autowired and second with constructor. I tried this way and it worked (Also not using CORS i.e. @CrossOrigin) . Edited above class.

Comment: Also in your controller try changing - 
  `@GetMapping("/test")
    public String testAdmin()  {
        return "OK; secret test admin";
    }`

Comment: It still doesn't work ; ( The code in the filter's method **never runs**.